# Calculation of VOCs concentration (ppm) in the headspace of a bottle

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, concentration

What is the right way to calculate the concentration of volatile compounds in the air in a closed container?

Suppose we have a $\pu{50 mL}$ bottle with $\pu{25 mL}$ of $100\%$ ethanol $(\ce{EtOH})$ in it.

In this case, will it be okay to use $PV = nRT?$

Doing so, it will be:

$$
\begin{align}
p(\ce{EtOH}) &= \pu{0.05872 atm}\\
V &= \pu{0.025 L}\\
R &= \pu{0.08206 L atm mol-1 K-1}\\
T &= \pu{298 K}\\
\end{align}
$$

giving us $n = \pu{6.00314E-5 mol}.$

The ppm: $\pu{1 ppm} = \pu{1 mg l-1}$

$$M(\ce{EtOH}) = \pu{46.07 g mol-1}$$

$$\pu{6.00314E-5 mol} × \pu{46.07 g mol-1} × 1000 =  \pu{2.766 mg}$$

This lead to $$[\pu{ppm}] = \frac{\pu{2.766 mg}}{\pu{0.025 l}} = \pu{110.6 ppm}$$

Comment: You have calculated the number of moles of ethanol. Do you need something else to find the concentration?

Comment: I just want to verify that it is the right way to calculate concentration of volatile liquids in the air? Thank you!

Comment: Just a couple more steps and you're done.

Comment: Thank you, made them, is it right? As this calculator giving me completely different answer http://madur.com/index.php?page=/partial_pressure

Comment: Don't you think approx.0.06 atm should lead to approx.60000 ppm v/v, even without any calculation ?

Answer (score 3):

Usage of ppm/ppb etc units is discouraged, as they are ambiguous without the explicit context. As generally, 1 ppm (w/w) <> 1 ppm (V/V) <> 1 ppm (n/n) <> 1 ppm (w/V).

It is recommended to use explicit units, like e.g mg/L.

Expecting ideal gas behaviour $pV = nRT$ is not reasonable.   Ideal gases are not in equilibrium with their liquid phase.

There should be rather used a [real gas equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_gas#Models).The easiest to use is the [van Der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation?wprov=sfla1), but even that has significant error near condensation state.

Additionally, the sample(!) temperature  has to be strictly controlled, otherwise $n$ would be variable.

Why not rather to use small volume of ethanol to be known to fully evaporate in given volume ? Or perhaps other solvent, unless ethanol is waterless.
Note that ethanol has significant deviation from the [Raoult's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoult%27s_law?wprov=sfla1).

---

I prefer $R = \pu{8.31446 J K-1 mol-1}$

Note that by [May 2019 redefinition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant?wprov=sfla1), 
 It's exact value is $\pu{8.31446261815324 J K-1 mol-1}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will follow your advises to try to calculate a more reasonable number. Could you please also advise on the ppm calculation in that case? Thank you!

Comment: @VGranin ppm is ambiguous: w/w, V/V, n/n ?

Comment: Pure liquid water would be 1,000,000 ppm w/w, V/V, n/n, and m/V. Pure steam at normal pressure and a temperature a bit above the normal boiling point on the other hand would be 1,000,000 ppm w/w, V/V, n/n, but ~800 w/V because the density of steam is much lower than that of liquid water.

Comment: Using ppm is a recipe for disaster...

Comment: Engineer here. Using the vapour pressure and the ideal gas law (IGL) will usually give a sufficiently accurate solution for gases for which $\dfrac{R\cdot T}{P} > 20 \frac{L}{g\ mol}$.

That said, if you want to correlate vapour-liquid equilibrium, using the IGL is not a good idea.